# excel printing in to different column

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import xlrd
import os

path = "data"
dirList=os.listdir(path)
f = open('', 'w')
f.write('')
f.write("\n")

for file in dirList:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path,file)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath) == 1:
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(fullpath)
        wb.sheet_names()
        sh = wb.sheet_by_name(u'')

        for j in range(0,sh.nrows):
            f.write(str(sh.cell(j,0).value))
            f.write(", ")
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(str(sh.cell(j,1).value))
            f.write(", ")
        f.write("\n")
```

This is the Script I have so far. I'm sorry about the last two questions. So I have excel files that have data values(numbers) under fist column labeled `x` and  second column labeled `y`. 10 of these excel files are saved in a folder called `RawTrack`. I'm trying to take the `x` and `y` values from all of the files and print it to a single excel file(`x_y_z_value.xls`). So I'm having trouble printing all of the `x` files in the first column and all of the `y` values in the second column. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a lot more context.  I cannot understand this question as is.

Comment: Ok, so what's actually going wrong? And what is in `sh`?

Comment: i just edited my question...im sorry. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think only a slight modification is required. You are putting a newline in between the x, y values that does not need to be there. This should produce rows with x, y.

```
    for j in range(21,sh.nrows):
        f.write(str(sh.cell(j,0).value))
        f.write(", ")
        f.write(str(sh.cell(j,1).value))
        f.write("\n")
```